# Creating and using classes in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create my own class and use it inside my controller, but i don't know exactly how. I did the following:

1. I created a php file which contains my class in a sub-folder inside the App folder. the php file (class) is called JunkFunction and the sub-folder is called myClasses.
2. In my controller i insert this line of code on the top :

   `use App\myClasses\JunkFunction;`
3. I create an object of the class as the following:

   `$function = new JunkFunction;`

But this exception is thrown :

> Class 'App\myClasses\JunkFunction' not found in D:\graduation
>   project\kh\app\Http\Controllers\UploadsController.php

Comment: Did you put `namespace App\myClasses;` in your class file?

Comment: Make sure the file is named `JunkFunction.php`, uses the correct namespace (`namespace App\myClasses;`), the class name is `class JunkFunction ...`, and if necessary, run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Thank you very much, i missed to put the namespace in my class file.

Comment: ya , this is namespace issue, put *<code>* namesapce App\myClasses *</code>*

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways you can create a class in laravel (recommend)

**1. Create a Model**
This is the most recommended way to create a class in laravel.
command to create a model: `php artisan make:model ModelName`
then you can use it as a `use App\ModelName;`

**2. As a helper**
This is no recommend.This one only use when you need a function/class exist in anywhere in the project so you cannot create class/function in same names.

- first create your class/function file and add it into the app folder.
- Then open your composer.json file and add your file path inzide of autoload part

  `"autoload": {
      "files": [
        "app/YourFunction.php"
      ]
    }`
- then run `composer dump-autoload`

and you are done.

Answer (score 4):

```
namespace App\myClasses;
```

put the namespace on top of file